# Butchered Ruby on Rails Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, fedora, uninstallation

So first off, this is my first post on stackoverflow, so take it easy on me ;)

I'm a new Fedora user (f20) and I'm still in the early stages of getting used to linux. I tried to install Ruby on Rails (newest Ruby—2.1.1—and newest rails—4.1.0), using several guides I found online, which required for me to download and install several other packages. Several errors occurred towards the end of my installation so I thought I'd uninstall it and start from scratch using RVM which I hadn't done in the first place.

I tried removing the gems I installed using `gem uninstall [gem_name]` but I wasn't having any luck with many of them. So I decided to just `sudo yum remove ruby` in the hopes it would remove everything I had installed, but to my dismay the directory `/usr/share/ruby` still exists which makes me think that my uninstallation was incomplete.

Is there some why to *completely* remove any shred of ruby, rails, and gems from my computer so I can reinstall ruby on rails? Is it even necessary for me to do so in order to install a lower version of ruby (2.1.0)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're on linux, the only inkling that those things exist are the folders and potentially environment variables. You could search for those keywords and determine if it's in a place you can remove. If your OS does not rely on `/usr/shared/ruby` it should be save to remove.

Comment: @izuriel _"You can search for those keywords and determine if it's in a place you can remove"_ Sorry, I don't quite understand that sentence. Which "keywords" am I searching for? And with what and where am I searching? And how do I know if my OS does not rely on on `usr/shared/ruby`? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Lots of reading. I don't use Fedora so I can't give any first hand advice but I've removed a few broken this before. As for keywords, "ruby", "gem" and "rails." As for searching, there is a nifty command line tool called `find` and the easiest way to get information about it is to pop open your console and type `man find`. Linux is a whole new world, dive right in.

Comment: If you're using rvm, theoretically it should be ok if the system ruby installation still exists. Ideally, you'll be using [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) to compartmentalize your ruby usage. Once you're using gemsets via rvm, just make sure you run the command `which ruby` to see which ruby installation you're using in your current environment. If you're using the ruby version under the `.rvm` folder, you should be good to go... theoretically. Similarly you can use `which gem` to find out which gem installation you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after reading the comments I figured out the problem!

I ran a `yum list | grep ruby` and similar searches and found that I had not, contrary to what I believed, removed all the packages I had installed. After deleting the remaining packages my `usr/share/ruby` folder vanished to the sound of my yipee's!

Thanks

Comment: You can accept your own answers to signal to other users this is the solution to your problem. Also, good work resolving the issue!

Comment: @izuriel Yeah, I tried but the system wouldn't let me until a few days passed. I suppose I tried to answer my own problem too soon after I posed it.